# blank screen after ipv6.disable=1 removal from grub cmdline

Tags: linux-mint, boot, grub2, ipv6, troubleshooting

I want to re-enable IPv6 on my system which is currently disabled in GRUB directly. But if I remove `ipv6.disable=1`, I then get a blank (backlit) screen.

<sub>It took me tonight to figure out that I have a `timeshift` backup of OS (Linux Mint 21.3), I have then been able to revert to a 20-day old state.</sub>

---

I have tested various combinations of GRUB cmdline via `e`dit during boot. **The only change that seems to conflict with some parts of the boot process is removing `ipv6.disable=1`** from the grub cmdline, the same result goes for `ipv6.disable=0`. I have no clue what could be in conflict, literally no idea.

---

Here is my grub config file before changes (my goal is to re-enable IPv6):

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=countdown
GRUB_TIMEOUT=3
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="fsck.mode=force fsck.repair=yes rootflags=data=journal ipv6.disable=1"
# GPU-related wakeup from suspend issue FIX
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.modeset=0"
```

---

Any assistance is highly appreciated.

---

### MAJOR UPDATE, changes everything

It actually does show my desktop after about 2 minutes and 30 seconds. (on my stopwatch)

Some maybe useful info:

```
$ systemd-analyze blame

5.842s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
1.638s fwupd.service
1.415s postfix@-.service
1.294s vboxdrv.service
1.118s dev-loop11.device
1.117s dev-loop10.device
1.114s dev-loop17.device
1.113s dev-loop16.device
1.105s dev-loop18.device
1.105s dev-loop15.device
1.105s dev-loop14.device
1.104s dev-loop13.device
1.098s dev-loop12.device
1.056s snapd.service
 940ms dev-loop4.device
 940ms dev-loop2.device
 939ms dev-loop1.device
 938ms dev-loop3.device
 937ms dev-loop0.device
 937ms dev-loop7.device
 934ms dev-loop6.device
 934ms dev-loop5.device
 863ms dev-nvme0n1p2.device
 766ms dev-loop9.device
 539ms snapd.seeded.service
 460ms networking.service
 367ms loadcpufreq.service
 363ms accounts-daemon.service
 338ms avahi-daemon.service
 316ms bluetooth.service
 308ms binfmt-support.service
 308ms NetworkManager.service
 308ms apport.service
 307ms cups.service
 304ms mnt-5tb.mount
 304ms apparmor.service
 298ms netfilter-persistent.service
 281ms dev-loop8.device
 277ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
 271ms networkd-dispatcher.service
 257ms udisks2.service
 249ms polkit.service
 238ms mono-xsp4.service
 218ms systemd-binfmt.service
 214ms lm-sensors.service
 205ms grub-common.service
 202ms systemd-resolved.service
 189ms systemd-logind.service
 185ms systemd-journal-flush.service
 182ms switcheroo-control.service
 181ms rsyslog.service
 176ms e2scrub_reap.service
 176ms gpu-manager.service
 164ms secureboot-db.service
 156ms user@1000.service
 152ms blueman-mechanism.service
 143ms wpa_supplicant.service
 142ms thermald.service
 138ms nvidia-persistenced.service
 129ms user@0.service
 124ms snap-bare-5.mount
 124ms ModemManager.service
 122ms systemd-timesyncd.service
 122ms snap-core-16202.mount
 120ms snap-core-16574.mount
 120ms dns-clean.service
 117ms snap-core18-2796.mount
 114ms snap-core18-2812.mount
 113ms upower.service
 112ms snap-core20-2105.mount
 112ms snap-core20-2182.mount
 111ms mnt-windows.mount
 110ms snap-gimp-418.mount
 108ms snap-gimp-428.mount
 106ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-194.mount
 106ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-198.mount
 104ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4966\x2dE925.service
 104ms ubuntu-system-adjustments.service
 103ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-140.mount
 103ms lightdm.service
 101ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-143.mount
  98ms snap-gtk2\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-13.mount
  98ms mnt-qvo.mount
  97ms console-setup.service
  96ms keyboard-setup.service
  95ms snap-gtk2\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-9.mount
  92ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1534.mount
  89ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1535.mount
  86ms snap-kde\x2dframeworks\x2d5\x2dcore18-32.mount
  86ms systemd-udevd.service
  85ms update-notifier-download.service
  84ms finalrd.service
  84ms systemd-remount-fs.service
  84ms snap-kde\x2dframeworks\x2d5\x2dcore18-35.mount
  81ms systemd-modules-load.service
  80ms modprobe@fuse.service
  80ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
  77ms modprobe@drm.service
  76ms alsa-restore.service
  75ms modprobe@configfs.service
  72ms systemd-journald.service
  70ms colord.service
  69ms smartmontools.service
  68ms phpsessionclean.service
  64ms kmod-static-nodes.service
  61ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount
  55ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
  55ms grub-initrd-fallback.service
  52ms cpufrequtils.service
  51ms dev-mqueue.mount
  46ms dev-hugepages.mount
  45ms ssh.service
  44ms snapd.apparmor.service
  41ms boot-efi.mount
  38ms openvpn.service
  35ms plymouth-read-write.service
  30ms systemd-update-utmp.service
  30ms sys-kernel-config.mount
  29ms packagekit.service
  28ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
  27ms systemd-random-seed.service
  26ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
  25ms systemd-sysusers.service
  24ms systemd-sysctl.service
  21ms systemd-user-sessions.service
  17ms systemd-backlight@leds:dell::kbd_backlight.service
  17ms kerneloops.service
  16ms modprobe@efi_pstore.service
  16ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
  11ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
   9ms systemd-rfkill.service
   9ms ifupdown-pre.service
   9ms nvmf-autoconnect.service
   9ms snapd.socket
   8ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
   7ms user-runtime-dir@0.service
   5ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
   5ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
   4ms vboxweb-service.service
   4ms setvtrgb.service
   3ms vboxautostart-service.service
   3ms rtkit-daemon.service
   3ms vboxballoonctrl-service.service
   1ms postfix.service
```

Comment: Possibly unrelated but I cannot read the *nomodeset* kernel parameter set while you apparently want *nouveau.modeset=0*. I had understood that if you wanted to disable modesetting (with nvidia cards) both had to be set.

Comment: @MC68020 Thank you for any suggestions. That I will try once I finish some work. I know I tried `nomodeset`, but I did not experiment with it really much. So I will try that again. Thanks again.

Comment: Is the blank screen always happening? Can't it be the final display manager (because I vaguely remember about old bugs on a display manager for IPv6, but the other way around: when removed)? Can the system still be booted in rescue/single-user mode on console (it would have to work first when also disabled), or can the issue be debugged remotely from ssh, to pinpoint what doesn't start?

Comment: @A.B This is my primary computer, already have thought about making SSH access to it, will do it once I finish some work. Thank you.

Comment: @A.B I have a hard time to make time today... Will have to postpone it to tomorrow. Thank you

Comment: @MC68020 I have a hard time to make time today... Will have to postpone it to tomorrow. Thank you

Comment: Look for any error messages in system logs or `dmesg`, that might indicate the cause of the blank screen...

Comment: I know it is silly question - Did you update the grub after making the change?  With `sudo update-grub`

Comment: @tukan Yes and this was a _mistake_ I repeated several times. Don't have time now, will have to postpone again.

Comment: @VlastimilBurián I see, take your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, this morning I made time for this. Upon SSH'ing to my machine from a second computer, it appeared as if it worked normal, no error trails in `dmesg` or `syslog` directly.

It sufficed to `update-grub` and boot twice. The first time it took considerable time to show desktop, but the second time it booted in normal time.